# FragmentActivity onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I try to use the Android compatibility library (or now called the support library) v4 for pre-honeycomb android devices.  I understand that, instead of using the Fragment class, I should use the FragmentActivity class.  According to all the tutorials I can find, I can use the **onCreateView** method as in the Fragment class:

***public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)***

However, the onCreateView method in the FragmentActivity seems to be different.  The one I inherit from is:

***public View onCreateView (String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)***

This version is actually listed in the Android reference of the FragmentActivity class.
Seems all tutorials I can find do not state this difference, and all are calling the one in the Fragment class.
Am I mistaking something here that I should be somehow able to call the onCreateView of the Fragment class version?

Comment: "I understand that, instead of using the Fragment class, I should use the FragmentActivity class.." this is BS... instead of `android.app.Activity` class you should use `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` and instead of `android.app.Fragment` you should use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: Thanks guys.  Yes, it is my fault and I knew that I must be doing something stupid since it seems to be a "problem" only to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is wrong:

> I understand that, instead of using the Fragment class, I should use the FragmentActivity class.

You should use FragmentActivity class insted of Activity class. In FragmentAcivity class it's enough that you override onCreate method.

Answer (score 4):

FragmentActivity and Activty are same.
FragmentActivity  is for Version (below 4)which are supports Fragment by using android.support.v4.jar .
For Versions from 4 there is no FragmentActivity..u can check it out.
FragmentActivity is for Calling showing Fragments..so u should not extends FragmentActivity  when u develop fragment View.
Fragments are part of the FragmentActivity.u can have more framgents.
for ur doubt:check this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet%29

Answer (score 2):

You've got it a little switched around.  Fragment is still Fragment.  Activity becomes FragmentActivity.  Have a peek at the sample code that comes with the Android Compatibility Library.  In particular, see `FragmentLayoutSupport.java`.

Comment: Your reply is obviously also correct, but gutiory's reply came a little bit earlier.  I did read the sample but not careful enough, and tried to jump to convert my existing app.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple delete your gen folder...worked for me